# Using curl on my Ubuntu 13.04 in an attempt to connect to Win & web service

Tags: curl

I am issuing the following on my Ubuntu in an attempt to connect to a WebService on a Win 7 machine on my intranet.

`curl http://192.168.0.10/CISWebService`

and the error I get is:-
curl: (7) Failed connect to `192.168.0.10:80`; Connection timed out
However a ping to that PC works fine.

am I doing something wrong or is the webservice at fault?

Answer (score 0):

It means that port 80 is either not accessible to you, or the web server on that IP address is not listening on port 80.

Comment: Now I need to wait for the Windows "expert" to sort that PC. Thanks for the answer.